# Ember js: binding to strings in a list

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/C3quh/1/

i am directly binding to strings in the collection. Although values from the array show up as values in the textbox. changing the value in the textbox doesn't change the value in the array.
how do i make this work?

Comment: I think you linked to the wrong jsFiddle.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to positions in an array. Instead, you should populate your arrays with Ember.Objects. Then, you can bind to a property on each of those objects.